# PowerPivot can't connect to OData WebAPI

Tags: excel, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404, odata, powerpivot

When I try to connect to my localhosted Odata WebAPI from Excel 2010 PowerPivot I got 404: Not found error.

Actually, PowerPivot can explore the list of my endpoints and says that connection successful. But when I press Finish button it shows 404.

Strange, but Fiddler captures nothing!

Please suggest. Thank you!

Comment: Is this similar to this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463168/give-odata-service-document-base-url-a-trailing-slash-in-webapi-odata

Comment: Yes! My fault. This is duplication.

Comment: I have answered this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463168/give-odata-service-document-base-url-a-trailing-slash-in-webapi-odata