# Excel Power-Pivot shows 404 when requesting OData endpoint

Tags: excel, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404, odata, powerpivot

Power-Point on Excel 2010 connects fine to OData WebAPI and finds all endpoints. However, when trying to retrieve data Power-Pivot shows 404 error.

The API returns XML by default in Browser and Fiddler. When Power-Pivot connects to API and trying to retrieve data NO entries in Fiddler.

Please suggest. Thank you very much!

Comment: Check what accept header is being sent by Excel.

Comment: I would, but Fiddler doesn't capture anything. Also, the request takes  a lot of time before returning any format but Power-Pivot gives error immediately. Also, I checked with both: JSON and XML returned by default. Result is the same. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using Power Query instead to pull in your data from the OData feed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PowerPivot can't connect to OData WebAPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677331/powerpivot-cant-connect-to-odata-webapi)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677331/powerpivot-cant-connect-to-odata-webapi.  From the same OP.

Comment: Marie, Thank you for the suggestion! Power Query works! Do you have any idea why Power Pivot doesn't?

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with the authentication mechanism? Do you have to log in to get to your OData feed? blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbi/archive/2013/12/13/one-step-closer-to-simplifying-data-analysis-and-visualization-new-features-added-to-power-bi-for-office-365-and-power-query-add-in-for-excel-preview.aspx

Comment: I have answered this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463168/give-odata-service-document-base-url-a-trailing-slash-in-webapi-odata